# How to set a cookie for sign up and login script

Tags: php, cookies

I am having problem in setting cookies. I have a sign up and login form from where after users are redirected to another page which includes `header.php` which is to show different data to logged in users and guest visiters(not logged in). But after sign up and login header menus are still sign up and login

`register.php`

```
 <?php
  $con = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","findfriends") or die ("Connection not established");
  ?>
  <?php
  if(isset($_POST['reg'])){
   $fn=strip_tags(@$_POST['fname']);
   $ln=strip_tags(@$_POST['lname']);
   $un=strip_tags(@$_POST['username']);
   $em=strip_tags(@$_POST['email']);
   $pswd=strip_tags(@$_POST['password']);
   $d= date("Y-m-d");
   $reg_query = "INSERT INTO users (userid,username,first_name,last_name,email,password,sign_up_date,activated,bio,profile_photo,closed) VALUES ('','{$un}','{$fn}','{$ln}','{$em}','{$pswd}','{$d}','0','What you do?','','no')";
   $reg_run = mysqli_query($con,$reg_query); 
   setcookie('user',$un,time()+3600*24*365);  
    echo "The cookie has been set."; 
    header("Location:main.php");

   if(isset($_POST['login'])){ 
   $log_que = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = '$un' AND password = '$pswd' ";
   $log_run = mysqli_query($con, $log_que);
   $row = mysqli_fetch_array($log_run);
   $un_db = $log_row['username'];
   $pswd_db = $log_row['password'];
   if($un == $un_db && $pswd == $pswd_db)
    {
    echo "LOGGED IN!";  
    setcookie('user',$un,time()+3600*24*365); 
    header("Location: main.php");
   }
   }
   ?>
```

`header.php`

```
        <!DOCTYPE html>
        <html>
        <head>
        <title>findfriends</title>
        <script src="js/main.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="./css/style.css"/>        
        </head>
        <body>
        <div class="headerMenu">
        <div id="wrapper">
        <div class="logo">
        <img src="./img/logo.gif"/>
        </div>
        <div class="search_box">
        <form action="searchresults.php" method="post" name="search">
        <table>
        <tr>
        <td>  
        <input type="text" name="search" placeholder="Search ..."/>
        </td>
        <td>
        <input type="image" src="./img/search-icon.png" alt="submit" />
        </td>
        </tr>
        </table>
        </form>
        </div>                
       <?php
       if(isset($_COOKIE['user'])){
       echo '
      <ul class="dd">
      <li><a href="main.php" >Home</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="' . $user . '">Profile</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="my_messages.php">Inbox' . $unread_numrows . '</a>
      </li> 
      <li><a href="#">Management</a>
      <ul><li><a href="account_settings.php">Settings</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="logout.php">Logout</a>
      </li>
      </ul>
      </li>
      </ul>';

     }
     else
    {
    echo '
    <ul class="dd">
    <li><a href="register.php" >Sign Up</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="register.php">Login</a>
    </li>
    </ul>';
    }
    ?>
    </div>
    </div>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: you are using two different cookie names for sign-ups and logins, is that intended?

Comment: Not totally sure what your actual problem is.. ..but your `header()` redirected will not work if you have `echo`'d stuff before them

Comment: what are the errors , u are getting??

Comment: ..nor will your second `setcookie()` work - for the same reason

Comment: sorry different names for cookies was just to test something else now question is edited thnks for reminding ;)

Comment: @MaggsWeb so should I use separate sign up and login pages?

Comment: No, just remove the `echo` lines.  There is no point `echo`ing anything, then redirecting - even if it did work (which it wont)

Comment: @MaggsWeb removed echo still doesn't work may be somethings wrong in `header.php` so added `header.php` to my question can you please review ques.

Answer (score 0):

You need to set output buffer on , if you do output before header function
Add it at your first line

```
<?php ob_start(); ?>
```

And at last

```
<?php ob_flush(); ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

you must add an if else statement in your login.php / login.html  file
 every file of your page

```
if($user===not_logged_in){
 header("Location: login.php");
} else{
//do somthing else
}
```